# Symfony2 - Apache crashes when using app.php

Tags: php, apache, symfony, segmentation-fault

When we use the `app_dev.php` page (development version), there is no problem, everything runs fine.

But when we try to access the app.php page, some pages tend to make Apache crash.

Here is our configuration:

- Debian 6 x64 with kernel 3.2.13
- Apache 2.2.22
- PHP 5.3.3-7+squeeze13
  with extensions: pdo / pdo_mysql / pdo_pgsql / pdo_sqlite / intl / apc / gd

A coredump gives us the following result:

```
#0  0x00007feab144e556 in zend_std_read_property (object=0x3, member=0x7feaa30ab840, type=3) at /tmp/buildd/php5-5.3.3/Zend/zend_object_handlers.c:340
#1  0x00007feab1463604 in zend_fetch_property_address_read_helper_SPEC_VAR_CONST (type=3, execute_data=0x7feab5cf5eb0) at /tmp/buildd/php5-5.3.3/Zend/zend_vm_execute.h:10084
#2  0x00007feab1453570 in execute (op_array=0x7feab5c863d8) at /tmp/buildd/php5-5.3.3/Zend/zend_vm_execute.h:107
#3  0x00007feab1420ef4 in zend_call_function (fci=0x7fff2689bfb0, fci_cache=0x0) at /tmp/buildd/php5-5.3.3/Zend/zend_execute_API.c:963
#4  0x00007feab1442047 in zend_call_method (object_pp=0x7fff2689c0d8, obj_ce=0x7feab63ea400, fn_proxy=0x7fff2689c0e8, function_name=0x7feab181e556 "__destruct", 
    function_name_len=646561136, retval_ptr_ptr=0x0, param_count=-1320891466, arg1=0x7fea00000000, arg2=0x0) at /tmp/buildd/php5-5.3.3/Zend/zend_interfaces.c:97
```

More details about the first frame:

```
#0  0x00007feab144e556 in zend_std_read_property (object=0x3, member=0x7feaa30ab840, type=3) at /tmp/buildd/php5-5.3.3/Zend/zend_object_handlers.c:340
340     property_info = zend_get_property_info(zobj->ce, member, (zobj->ce->__get != NULL) TSRMLS_CC);
```

The first argument sent, zobj->ce = 0x3, seemed suspicious, so I looked in zobj contents:

```
(gdb) p *zobj
$3 = {ce = 0xa5935461f887fe37, properties = 0xa5935461f8e5bbb7, guards = 0x0}
```

But what does contain zobj->ce ?

```
(gdb) p *(zobj->ce)
Cannot access memory at address 0xa5935461f887fe37
```

It seems this address leads to an invalid memory location.
What is disturbing is that this problem only occurs when using the production version of the Symfony2 app. It might indicate a problem with APC or another module only loaded with the production version, but we found no clue about what could cause this.

We tried to reinstall most PHP extensions we have installed, but with no result until then.

Edit: on demand, here is the app.php code, which is the original file shipped with Symfony2. I don't really believe it is the cause of the problem, though.

```
header('P3P: CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT');

require_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap.php.cache';
require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppKernel.php';
//require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppCache.php';

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
//$kernel = new AppCache($kernel);
$kernel->handle(Request::createFromGlobals())->send();
```

Comment: Could you attach contents of `app.php`?

Comment: The app.php code is added above, but there isn't anything really out of the ordinary in it.

Comment: Set the debug flag to true,  AppKernal('prod',true') and see what you get.

Comment: I guess that it would work better running the latest PHP version. You could try to use dotdeb.org to have up to date apt packages

Comment: I'm sorry if this sounds idiotic, but whenever I had production environment issues it was almost almost always caching issues. Are you pretty sure you cleared the cache? Even with rm -rf app/cache/* ?

Comment: Sorry for my late answer. Yes, I've cleaned the cache, numerous times. I actually used to do that each time I deploy the application. But I don't really need an answer anymore, as I am not working on this project anymore. Thanks all your help!